# A question about proving distinct Fermat numbers are relatively prime

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, fermat-numbers

I am reading [Elementary Number Theory with Programming](https://www.wiley.com/en-us/Elementary+Number+Theory+with+Programming-p-9781119062769), and bump into the proof of "The Fermat numbers $F_n$ and $F_m$ where m ≠ n are relatively prime.":

> Theorem: The Fermat numbers $F_n$ and $F_m$ where m ≠ n are relatively prime.
>
> Proof: Let n > m and let d = gcd($F_n$, $F_m$). Since $F_n$ and $F_m$ are odd, it follows that d is odd. We will show that d = 1. Let x = $2^{2^{m}}$ and let a = $2^{n−m}$. Then $F_n$ −2 = $2^{2^{n}}$ −1 = $x^a$ −1. Since a is even, x = −1 is a root of the equation $x^a$ − 1 = 0, implying that x + 1 | $x^a$ − 1. Then $F_m$| $F_n$− 2. Since d | $F_m$, it follows that d | $F_n$ − 2. Now, since, in addition, d | $F_n$, we have d | 2, implying that d = 1 since d is odd, and the proof is over.

I can understand all except the following words:

> Since a is even, x = −1 is a root of the equation $x^a$ − 1 = 0, implying that x + 1 | $x^a$ − 1.

How is "x + 1 | $x^a$ − 1" concluded?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint**. $x^2-1 = (x-1)(x+1)$ and $x^2 - 1 \mid x^{2n} -1$.

Comment: I still can't figure out why "x = −1 is a root of the equation $x^a$ − 1 = 0" can deduce "x + 1 | $x^a$ - 1". What is the relationship between these 2 statements.

Comment: Well, if $b$ is a root of a polynomial $P$, then $X-b$ divides $P$. Indeed, do the Euclidian division, $P = Q(X-b) + R$, with $d(R) < d(X-b) = 1$, that is $d(R) = 0$. Since $P(b) = 0$, $R = 0$.